# SQL combining rows issue that probably relates to GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL code:

```
SELECT
    CH_USER4 AS 'Office',
    LEFT(CH_SORT, 3) AS 'Flt Lst Division',
    CH_USER5 AS 'Charter Type',
    CH_CODE AS 'Charter No',
    CH_DATE_REQ AS 'Flight Date',
    CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, CH_DATE_REQ) AS varchar(10)) + '-' + REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(mm, CH_DATE_REQ), 2), ' ', '0') AS 'Flight Month',
    MAX(C_COST-CH_ACTUAL_COST) AS 'Budget Outstanding',
    MAX(C_COST) AS 'Flt List Costs',
    CASE
        WHEN DET_NOM_YEAR = 'C' 
             AND DET_PERIODNUMBR <= '7' 
            THEN IIF(DET_TYPE = 'CRN', -(DET_NETT), DET_NETT)
            ELSE 0
    END AS 'YTD Nominal',
    CASE
        WHEN
            CH_DATE_REQ >= '2023-02-01' 
            AND CH_DATE_USER1 <= '2023-08-31' 
           THEN MAX(C_COST)
           ELSE 0
    END AS 'C/Y Flt List Costs'
FROM 
    CST_COSTHEADER
LEFT JOIN 
    AT_BUDGETTOTAL ON CST_COSTHEADER.CH_CODE = AT_BUDGETTOTAL.CC_COPYHEADER
LEFT JOIN 
    SL_PL_NL_DETAIL on CST_COSTHEADER.CH_CODE = SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_COSTHEADER
WHERE 
    CH_CODE = 'IR001565'
    AND DET_COSTCENTRE not like 'ZINC'
GROUP BY 
    CH_CODE, C_COST, CH_USER4, CH_SORT, CH_USER5, CH_DATE_REQ, CH_ACTUAL_COST, DET_NOM_PERIOD, DET_NOM_YEAR, DET_NETT, DET_PERIODNUMBR, CH_DATE_USER1, DET_TYPE
```

This produces this output:

[image]

However, I am trying to group this to just produce one line where `Budget Outstanding`, `Flt List Costs` and `C/Y Flt List Costs` are the `MAX`...so 0, 18077.15 and 18077.15 respectively and `YTD Nominal` is the sum of all the rows (so 9077.15).

I'm sure it has something to do with the `GROUP BY` but I just can't work it out

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you aggregating *and* grouping on the same columns? For example, you ask for the `MAX` of `C_COST`, but `C_COST` is also in your `GROUP BY`. The `MAX` of a distinct value of `C_COST` is always going to be that distinct value of `C_COST`.

Comment: @ThomA - thanks for your reply....I had the `MAX` in there as believing this may have been an issue, which I understand is not now so have removed but still struggling to group everything correctly...

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some *consumable* sample and expected results then.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post...the expected result of what was provided is to group all rows with `Charter No` being the changing factor - everything is linked to this column in the different tables. The `YTD Nominal` column is the only column with different amounts whereas the other three numeric columns will always be the same...so would need to sum `YTD Nominal` to just show one record for `Charter No` IR001565

Comment: From what I understood you want to group by  `CH_CODE `, right? So what is stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at a single row with maximums for some columns you need to group by only those columns that are needed to define each row. In other words, ONLY group by columns that do NOT need an aggregate function.

Also, when aggregating columns with conditions you can place the entire case expression inside the aggregations. e.g. `MAX(case when x = 1 then value end)` (this is known as a "conditional aggregate").

With these points in mind (and some other suggestions) I believe your query would be more like this:

```
SELECT
      CH_USER4 AS [Office]
    , LEFT(CH_SORT, 3) AS [Flt Lst Division]
    , CH_USER5 AS [Charter Type]
    , CH_CODE AS [Charter No]
    , CH_DATE_REQ AS [Flight Date]
    , CONVERT(CHAR(7), CH_DATE_REQ, 121) AS [Flight Month] -- YYYY-MM is simpler this way
    , MAX(C_COST - CH_ACTUAL_COST) AS [Budget Outstanding]
    , MAX(C_COST) AS [Flt List Costs]
    , SUM(CASE
          WHEN DET_NOM_YEAR = 'C' AND DET_PERIODNUMBR <= '7'  AND DET_TYPE = 'CRN'  THEN  - DET_NETT
          WHEN DET_NOM_YEAR = 'C' AND DET_PERIODNUMBR <= '7'  AND DET_TYPE <> 'CRN' THEN DET_NETT 
          ELSE 0 
          END) AS [YTD Nominal]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN CH_DATE_REQ >= '2023-02-01' AND CH_DATE_USER1 <= '2023-08-31' THEN C_COST 
          ELSE 0 
          END) AS [C/Y Flt List Costs]
FROM CST_COSTHEADER
LEFT JOIN AT_BUDGETTOTAL ON CST_COSTHEADER.CH_CODE = AT_BUDGETTOTAL.CC_COPYHEADER
LEFT JOIN SL_PL_NL_DETAIL ON CST_COSTHEADER.CH_CODE = SL_PL_NL_DETAIL.DET_COSTHEADER
WHERE CH_CODE = 'IR001565'
    AND DET_COSTCENTRE NOT LIKE 'ZINC'
GROUP BY
      CH_USER4
    , LEFT(CH_SORT, 3)
    , CH_USER5
    , CH_CODE
    , CH_DATE_REQ
```

Notes:

- while you can use single quotes for column names, usually these are reserved for use with literals. For columns names use double quotes or square brackets
- CONVERT(CHAR(7), CH_DATE_REQ(), 121) formats a date to YYYY-MM in a single function call, limiting the output to 7 chars is "the trick"
- I suggest avoiding use of IIF() inside a case expression, but this is personal preference really.
- if column `DET_PERIODNUMBR` is an integer then do NOT quote the '7', instead `DET_PERIODNUMBR <= 7`

Comment: amazing thank you for this and all the helpful tips - thank you for all the helpful tips....one issue I did get was that I was getting a `'CH_DATE_REQ' is not a recognized built-in function name` error

Comment: actually I've just noticed that `YTD Nominal` comes back with 10251.35 only and not sums this column?

Comment: So, if you want sum(), use that instead of max().

Comment: Sorry there were parentheses after

Comment: CH_DATE_REQ() changed. Removed the () that was a mistake.

Comment: Awesome - thank you for all your help, this has done the trick